# How can I make website objects appear to fadeout as you scroll? (Transparent gradient)

Tags: web, png, gradient, transparent, fadeout

I have a website with some text on the body and a fixed menu bar on top.

I want the text to 'fade-out' as you scroll, instead of disappearing behind other element.

My website's background is grey, so II made a gradient that goes from grey to transparent.

It works great, except that you can sort of tell that there's a grey band across the website.

[Notice the band (starting right above the red arrow) on this screen I printed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9lhg.png)

Why does irt show an off color?

I know about PNG gamma correction, but this is not it, I have removed the gAMA part, I have also tried "fine-tuning" it, nothing will work. (I know I am doing this right because I tried it on a solid PNG, stripped the gamma data, and it perfectly matches the CSS background).

Any ideas on how I can achieve this?! (I can use any other method, doesn't need to be a PNG gradient, but I do need it to be a fade-out).

Comment: Does anyone know just why the grey gradient makes a dark band? Shouldn't the color just disappear?

Answer (score 0):

Make a gradient from opaque gray to transparent **white**.

Comment: Thanks mate, I just tried it but it seems to give me the exact same gradient (and looks the same on the browser). I'm on Photoshop CS3, did  it on the Gradient Editor... Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry man I was doing it wrong. It does give you a completely different gradient, but it does not do. The white starts to show before the transparent kicks in (so to speak) so you can see a white band now instead of a grey one...